# DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter '2' from the data source for row '0'

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi any one can help  me i am using datatables for pagintion where i am geting   waring:
**DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row '0'**

here is my code:

```
<?php 

include "admin/config.php";

$table="t_bad_order_report";
$select=$cfg->select("$table ORDER BY orderid DESC","");


?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" /> 


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css" />


    <!-- Data Table -->
    <!-- JQuery v1.9.1 -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/datatables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables-conf.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.css" />



</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

          </div>
           <div class="col-sm-10" id="loginas" style="background-color:white"; class="table-responsive">
             <h1>Welcome Admin</h1>


            </div>
              <div class="col-sm-10" id="badorder" style="background-color:white;" class="table-responsive">



                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="basic-datatable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Name</th>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                        <?php 
                                        $count=0;
                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){ ?>
                                        <tr>
                                              <td><?php echo $row['store']; ?> </td>




                                        </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated, just curious...did you notice that you're including `jquery.dataTables.css` twice?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between number of `th` and `td`.
Try like this:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['store']; ?> </td>
 </tr>
```